# Connecting to MySQL Remotely on Azure VM

Tags: azure, networking, mysql

I am having trouble connecting remotely to my MySql install that runs on an Azure VM.

Here is what I did:

- Ubuntu VM with MySql 5.7 installed
- Bind Address set to 0.0.0.0 [image]
- User granted rights with wildcard domain
- Opened 3306 on Azure networking page [image]

I can connect using MySql Workbench if I use the ssh credentials, but not directly.

I cannot connect with telnet, which tells me that the issue is with Networking, but I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Are you using a "managed" Azure Database for MySQL?  Or did you create a VM and manually create the DB within the VM?

Comment: Created a DB within the VM